# How can I get the direction of a cube's face after rotating the cube by increments of 90 degrees?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

I am trying to rotate a cube in 3D space and I want to figure out the orientation of any of its faces after the cube has been rotated by increments of 90 degrees. Here's a diagram showing how I think of each face at a default rotation of 0,0,0:[image: a cube with 6 different faces. north, south, east, west, top, bottom]

The function arguments would be one of the six faces of the cube as well as the rotation that I want to apply to it. The returned value would be the new orientation of that face. For instance, **getFaceRotation(east, (0,90,0)) = south**. In other words, if I want to know the direction of the east face after rotating the cube 90 degrees around the y axis, then the operation should return the south face.

I'm specifically doing this in Unity which uses Quaternions.

I feel like I'm overthinking this but all of my search attempts direct me to a lot of calculus that sort of touches on my question but nothing has helped me just return the rotation of a single face. If someone could help me with this, I would be very grateful.

Edit: I need this to account for any possible vector3 set of coordinate values equal to 0, 90, 180, or 270. So this would include anything like (180, 90, 270), (0, 180, 90), etc.

Comment: This is a two dimensional problem and not a three dimension.  First your z-axis is backwards.  Using the right hand rule of thumb.  If you wrap your fingers from x to y your thumb should point to positive z.  You picture has positive z in the wrong direction.

Comment: @jdweng the program that I am using uses the left-hand coordinate system.

Comment: Using Left hand none of the conventional math will work.  Use Polar Coordinates to understand problem  each face of the cube is perpendicular to a vector so you do not have to worry about the faces, just the vectors to the face.  North/South, East/West, Top/Bottom are just names assigned to vectors.  So just calculate the angles and then associate the angles to the names.  The problem is trivial.  You are just rotating a vector 90 degrees at a time along one of the 3 axis using polar coordinates.  See : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154743/how-to-rotate-a-polar-equation

Answer (score 0):

Use the transform axis to know your face directions

- `transform.up` will give you the `y` axis
- `transform.forward` will give you the `z` axis
- `transform.right` will give you the `x` axis

Then you can compare the transform axis with a `Vector3` axis such as `Vector3.up` and so on.

I have made a simple scene to test, try using this script on your cube component.

```cs
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log($"top face = {FaceDirection(transform.up)}");
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, 90));
        Debug.Log($"top face = {FaceDirection(transform.up)}");
        transform.Rotate(new Vector3(270, 0, 0));
        Debug.Log($"top face = {FaceDirection(transform.up)}");
    }
    string FaceDirection(Vector3 face)
    {
        string direction = "";
        if (face == Vector3.up)
            direction = "Top";
        else if (face == Vector3.down)
            direction = "Bottom";
        else if (face == Vector3.right)
            direction = "East";
        else if (face == Vector3.left)
            direction = "West";
        else if (face == Vector3.up)
            direction = "North";
        else if (face == Vector3.down)
            direction = "South";
        return direction;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You result should be like picture below

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I think I might not have been clear enough in my question. I edited it to make it more clear as I need this to return the value of where a starting face will end up after being rotated. I think I am also having trouble understanding the table that you've provided in respect to the question

Comment: However, this does give me some good ideas for how I might approach this problem